# When should we create posts in Meta about a declined flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Discussing a declined flag on meta could help a new user find out why his flag was rejected, and be guided as to what should be flagged and how. Also, it could help a moderator fix the issue if the flag was wrongfully declined.

But what about older members that have an adequate understanding of the flag system? Should they bring up declined flags which might have been the result of a moderator mis-click?

Does the importance of the flag matter? E.g. a (wrongfully) declined flag on spam would be much more important than a (wrongfully) declined not-constructive `"+1 iterators are so fun"` comment.

---

So, in general..

- Should *all* declined flags that were wrongfully declined (or perceived as wrongfully declined) be brought to meta?

If not:

- When should a post be created in Meta about a declined flag?
- Does the urgency/importance of the flagged issue matter?
- Are there any other factors that should be taken into account when creating a meta post about a declined flag?

Comment: You're talking about post flags, not comment flags, right?

Comment: In general, probably more of a gray area in the middle where there isn't a right answer, but I'd say opening a meta question to discuss any declined **comment** flag is a terrible idea.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is there a difference? If the answer can't cover both cases, i could narrow the question to either one.

Comment: @Fermi, the sheer volume and relative subjectiveness of comment flags pretty much guarantee a complete shitstorm heading our way. If that ever comes to be, such posts should have a dedicated tag and I will be *actively* ignoring that tag.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Good. Then my question can be both about declined comments *and* posts, and part of the answer could be your above comment, in order to prevent/reduce meta-posts about declined comment-flags.

Comment: That won't reduce the actual traffic, though, and the moderators will not be able to ignore the tag. I wouldn't want to be in their shoes if this is implemented.

Answer (score 8):

IMO, it's fine to start a meta question discussing declined flags of any sort, but there's a pretty big caveat.  There's already lots of past discussion over declined flags (especially NAA).  Because of this, a lot of new questions about declined flags are duplicates, so those questions should be closed or never posted.  Just like on the main site, you need to research and try to find the answer before posting the question.  If existing answers don't answer your question fully, then ask it (pointing out why your questions isn't a duplicate).

---

Answering your questions specifically:

> Should all declined flags that where wrongfully declined (or perceived as wrongfully declined) be brought to meta?

No.  A lot of these are exact duplicates that should not be posted.  A lot of declined flags are answered either with "Your NAA flag was declined because the post appears to be a legitimate attempt to answer the question."  or "Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.  The community can already do that without moderator intervention."

> When should a post be created in Meta about a declined flag?

Whenever you have a question, and it's not answered sufficiently.

> Does the urgency/importance of the flagged issue matter?

Yes.  It is very important to resolve any confusion about the serious spam and offensive flags.  Those flags carry stiff penalties (for good reason) and need to be very accurately used.  Obviously some are still duplicates, but subtle differences can be very important in the correctness of these flags because they aren't community reversable.

> Are there any other factors that should be taken into account when creating a meta post about a declined flag?

Just the general meta question guidelines.  Do the research.  Clearly define the discussion/feature-request/whatever.  Don't make it sound like a rant. Try not to call specific users out on meta and avoid the meta effect.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room has a bunch of regulars with enough declined flags in their profile to quickly judge posts and if flags are warranted.