# Serial voting still showing on my questions 5 days after incident, cache not cleared as expected?

Tags: bug, serial-voting, caching

**This is not a duplicate of ["voting corrected" does not give the up votes back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333930/voting-corrected-does-not-give-the-up-votes-back).** Per [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333930/voting-corrected-does-not-give-the-up-votes-back#comment392531_333931) on the linked question, a midnight script should correct these votes, but this doesn't seem to be working... hence the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report.

---

I had multiple days of serial down votes on lots and lots of questions. As I understand it, when these were reversed the cached score on the question and in my profile should have reverted *"1-2 days later"*

The voting happened nearly a week ago and I'm still affected:

[image]
[image]

In my questions list of my profile I see:

[image]

Clicking into them still shows a negative value:

[image]

but when I expand the votes:

[image]

Refreshing the screen now shows:

[image]

and refreshing the questions screen on my profile now also updates:

[image]

Comment: I don't remember where I read it, but the reason for this is that the score isn't "recalculated" before you press the score to see the up - / down votes. - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333930/voting-corrected-does-not-give-the-up-votes-back

Comment: As the answer in the linked question states, it should auto update after 1 to 2 days.

Comment: Ok, well this hasn't. These instances happend last week

Comment: Maybe the scrips don't work weekends :)

Comment: If the scores aren't being recalculated after several days or even a week, I'd say something fishy is going on (or *not* going on in this case). I'd ask a dev's opinion on this.

Comment: You are or I should? @BoltClock Cos I don't know how to do that... :)

Comment: I mean, you'd have to wait for a dev to weigh in - hopefully one will notice your question now that you've posted it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help @BoltClock

Comment: If the (robo-)closevoters would read the comments before voting, I'd be soooo happy.

Comment: It seems like quite a few things haven't been running lately, but I wouldn't know why.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'd be even happier if there are penalties for robo-closing meta posts. Having someone with a profile full of grammar errors, close-vote [my answered post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315667/when-should-we-create-posts-in-meta-about-a-declined-flag) as "unclear what you are asking" is ridiculous.

Comment: @Fermi yeah I'm kind of done with Meta, given an incrowd of 5-10 people can decide what gets discussed on in. I've flagged this behavior multiple times, I've `@pinged` the users and nothing is being done about it.

Comment: @CodeCaster We should create a post about the problem, with examples of dumb close-votes. Meta should have a different policy/rewards/penalties when it comes to closing. I do agree that current Meta turns me away as well.

Answer (score 10):

Some of the daily scripts have been timing out - including the one that would fix this particular issue, meaning that vote corrections didn't complete.

We are looking at fixing those timeouts - that will sort out all discrepancies.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Comment: Not quite yet. Query optimisation is hard!